# ChangeDisplaySettings(NULL, 0) moves/resizes my window

Tags: c++, winapi, resize, window, fullscreen

I have a 800x600 window and this is the code I am using for toggling fullscreen mode:

```
void Window::SetFullscreen(bool value)
{
    if(_fullscreen == value)
    {
        return;
    }

    _fullscreen = value;

    if(_fullscreen)
    {
        SetWindowLongPtr(_window, GWL_STYLE, WS_POPUP);
        SetWindowPos(_window, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, _width, _height, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);

        EnumDisplaySettings(null, 0, &_devmode);

        _devmode.dmSize = sizeof(_devmode);
        _devmode.dmPelsWidth = _width;
        _devmode.dmPelsHeight = _height;
        _devmode.dmBitsPerPel = 32;         
        _devmode.dmFields = DM_BITSPERPEL | DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT;

        ChangeDisplaySettings(&_devmode, CDS_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"---"<<endl;
        ChangeDisplaySettings(null, 0);
        cout<<"---"<<endl;

        SetWindowLongPtr(_window, GWL_STYLE, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);
        SetWindowPos(_window, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    }
}
```

Everytime I go from fullscreen to windowed mode, ChangeDisplaySettings(null, 0); resizes my window to 1366x768 (wtf ??!?!) which is my default screen resolution. How can I prevent this? (Resizing the window back to 800x600 afterwards is not an acceptable option)

Comment: You could try intercepting the `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` message.

Comment: I expect it's not actually resizing the window at all - it's just keeping it in the size it was in full-screen mode. Why don't you save the position and size of your window when you go into fullscreen mode, and restore it when you go out?

Comment: You need to keep calling EnumDisplaySettings(), incrementing the 2nd argument, until you get one that you are happy width.

Comment: Solved it (sort of) by using `CloseWindow(_window)` before `ChangeDisplaySettings(null, 0)` and `ShowWindow(_window, SW_RESTORE)` afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You failed to respond to `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`. Had you returned 800x600 there, Windows would have known that your window can't resize to 1366x768.